# Ruby TracePoint: How to trap definition of a specific class?

Tags: ruby, class, tracepoint

I am trying to find out how to use Ruby's TracePoint API to trap the definition and subsequent redefinitions of a specific class (e.g. 'Resolv'). I am able to trap *all* class definitions using:

```
TracePoint.trace(:class) do |tp|
  require 'pry'; binding.pry # for example
end
```

However, I am unable to filter it using either `:class` or `:end` parameters so that I could trap only the `Resolv` class.  The `TracePoint` object has a `defined_class` attribute, but that contains who is self at the time of the class definition (which was `nil`, aka `(main)`), and not the class whose definition is about to be processed. Nor could I find a way to see which file and line were being processed.  There *is* a `binding` variable, but it contained no variables.

How can I do this?

Comment: Doesn't `tp.lineno` and `tp.path` give you the line and file?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I don't know how I missed that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I am aware of would be to trace *all* class definitions and filter them with [`TracePoint#self`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/TracePoint.html#method-i-self):

```
TracePoint.new(:end) do |tp|
  if tp.self == Resolv
    # yay, we are in
    # tp.disable # use this to unset a trace point
  end
end.enable
```